# Avoiding code injections with c# Driver for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, code-injection, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following code that checks if a user-entered email already exists in the collection:

```
MongoDatabase authdb = DatabaseManager.GetDatabase("authdb");
var userDocuments = authdb.GetCollection<UserDocument>(UserDocument.CollectionName);
var doc = userDocuments.FindOne(new QueryDocument("email", email));
```

I'm a little that using a value (email) supplied by user is opening an opportunity for sorts of injections, kind of like SQL injection. Is it a real problem and how to approach it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official docs are here.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Do+I+Have+to+Worry+About+SQL+Injection

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation states, the biggest area you need to watch out for is db.eval(). The .eval() method for the driver is going to be translated to equivalent javascript .eval function. You want to be extra careful when using .eval in javascript because it parses and executes that code represented by the string passed into the eval method.